# Кавычки в названиях

Tags: кавычки

В правилах сказано, что музыкальные коллективы употребляются в кавычках, а что скажете по поводу одиночных исполнителей, взявших псевдоним? Певец Джанго, например. Без кавычек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написание псевдонима в кавычках - грамматическая ошибка, основанная на банальном подражании написанию в других языках. Есть случаи "приобщения к великим музыкантам" путём переноса одного из английских способов записи прозвища/псевдонима - в кавычках между реальными именем и фамилией: Сергей «Паук» Троицкий (по аналогии с Colin 'Bomber' Hodgkinson, Terry 'Geezer' Butler и т. п.). Другой пример демонстративного вызова русской грамматике - написание заглавных букв в середине слова (МегаФон - юридически зарегистрировано такое название организации). Многие самодеятельные переводчики подобным способом переносят в русский из английского составные фамилии с заглавной буквой внутри слова. Надеюсь, нормой это никогда не станет.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, ну названия - это одно, а псевдонимы - совсем другое. Название, безусловно, надо писать в кавычках, а псевдоним - это ведь то же имя. Мы же не пишем в кавычках, например, свои ники в интернете или клички животных. Так и тут.

Comment: Спасибо! Поняла.